# How to flip a coordinate system in iText?

Tags: java, itext

When placing objects onto a pdf page using absolute positioning (within a `PdfContentByte` I'm guessing?), it's positioned within a coordinate system which starts in the lower left corner.

I'd like to flip the coordinates in a way the system begins in the upper left corner. I'd do the flipping prior to adding any content to the page.

I tried using this

`cb.concatCTM(1f, 0f, 0f, -1f, 0f, PageSize.A4.getHeight());`

but the objects added later were flipped (what I would not like to happen).

Comment: If you flip coordinate systems in PDFs, you automatically flip contents, too. If you merely want the origin in the top left and can work with negative y coordinates, a simple translation would do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases when you need the origin of the coordinate system to be in the upper-left corner, it is custom to use simple math to change the coordinates. Using a different CTM for this purpose is more complex and can lead to all kinds of side-effects, as you've experienced yourself. For instance: rotating the CTM also rotates the contents (text can be upside-down, mirrored,...).

Why not simply use a method that recalculates the coordinates. For instance: you want to have a coordinate (10, 10) counted from the top of the page, then use transform(pagesize, y) where the transform method is defined like this:

```
public float transform(Rectangle pagesize, float y) {
    return pagesize.top() - y;
}
```

This way you can do stuff like:

```
float x = 50;
float y = transform(pagesize, 50);
table.writeSelectedRows(0, 10, x, y, canvas);
```

Personally, I think it's a bad idea not to respect the coordinate system as defined in ISO-32000-1, because you prefer working with an odd coordinate system where increasing Y values point down instead of up (that's so counter-intuitive), but if you insist in doing so, you shouldn't tamper with the CTM unless your PDF fu is really big.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing that... Well it's all for my little project and since I read top to bottom and not the other way around, the original settings were contra-intuitive (for an amateur like me)...
Besides, I don't believe that anyone is going to read my code except me anyway. :D

Answer (score 3):

Any transformation you apply to the PDF coordinate system does not only change the way *you* can *supply the coordinates* of some point on the page; instead it also changes the coordinate system into which a *PDF viewer draws its objects*. E.g.

[image: Figure 13 - Effects of Coordinate Transformations]

> *(section 8.3.3* Common Transformations *in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

If you ***flip*** the coordinates in a way the system begins in the upper left corner, therefore, you also **flip** the objects drawn. In case of text objects you can locally undo the flipping by means of text matrices flipping back in situ.

This means quite a hassle, though. If it instead would suffice to have the origin in the upper left corner with negative y coordinates on the page, I would propose you merely translate the coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: forgive my English.  I'm spanish guy xD

Here is my solution:

I was looking for the same thing.  I wanted to have origin point at upper-left corner.

Well, you can't change it but you can do another thing.

If you want the heigh of EACH PAGE you must get the page's cropbox from PdfReader class.

So, for example, if you want to get the vertical position "y = 60" considerating origin at upper-left corner you have to do this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("yourFile.pdf");
Float y = reader.getCropBox(pageNumber).getHeight()-60;
```

This is very useful in the case you have a pdf document with differents pages height.

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me in my application:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("yourFile.pdf");
Float y = reader.GetPageSize(pageIndex).Height-60; 
Float y = reader.GetPageSize(pageIndex).Height-60-rectangleHeight;
```

Maybe you have to count with the dimensions of the added/manipulated object too.
I'm adding rectangles in my application.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. You need to add some explanation and format your answer